# Run HDFS only on Master in Hadoop Cluster Setup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Assuming that we have 4 available servers:

> would it be possible to have a HADOOP cluster setup on all these 4 servers **but run the DataNode (and of course the NameNode) only on the master** while all of the servers will be able to execute map/reduce jobs (but only requesting files from the one single running DataNode)?

So, the final configuration would be to have one master and three slaves, while the HDFS will run only on the master.
I recognise that this is not something useful and efficient but I am doing this for the sake of an experiment. Is there a way to configure HDFS to work like this?

Comment: So you want HDFS on one machine, and YARN on all?

Comment: Exactly! Is it possible to configure it this way?

Comment: Possible, perhaps, recommended, not at all. What have you tried, and what doesn't work? StackOverflow isn't really a "it is possible" site.

Comment: What I found so far, is how to configure which servers will be the slaves which will be the master but I could not find anything relevant to my question. A draft way, would be probably to kill manually the DataNode processes in the slaves (like `kill -9 <DataNode_process_id>`) but I wonder if there is any smarter way.

Comment: There should be a step during setup where you say which nodes are the datanodes and namenodes. I've only used GUI tools to do that, though, so I'm sure what the command process would be

Comment: Which installation are you using? You have at least two options:. 1) Tune your installation for not installing DataNode (for example we are using Ansible script where I can specify what services I would like to be installed and on which nodes). 2) Play with bash files, so you disable the startup of datanode (generally in /usr/lib/hadoop directory)